# ajax in ruby on rails doesn t send the data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, url, post

i am doing a test of ajax (because i am so new in ajax) to send data from the view welcome(index.html.erb) to the controller(welcome_controller.rb) but all the times that i have tried show me the same error:

[image]
with same change:
[image]

but i don t know what that mean and all the the times the view show me the alert "error"(error) when i do the request.

here is what i have done in the view:

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#petition").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.99.100:3000/welcome_controller/index/',
            type: 'POST',    
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { max_id: {id: "5"} },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {

                alert(xhr+status+error);    \\to take the second photo i change this for this "alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));" 
            }           
        });
    });
});
```

here is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :welcome do
    collection do
      get 'index'
    end
  end

  get 'welcome/page'
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'menu/index'
end
```

here is me application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery  
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require tinymce
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and here is the ruby gem:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?('/')
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

#propiedades de usuario
gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.1'

#text editor to post with link and imagens
gem 'tinymce-rails'

#admin y moderator
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'rolify'

#votar like y dislike
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.11.1'

#consultas rails para mesclar con js
gem 'jquery-rails'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
```

my controller name is :welcome_controller.rb
and have 2 method index and show i will put the controller anyways:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_welcome, only: [:show]
  protect_from_forgery :except => :receive_guest
  helper_method :current_or_guest_user

  def index
    puts params[:max_id]
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

Comment: The `$.ajax` call in your JavaScript isn't the problem, the problem is how you're trying to include jQuery in the page. You should probably have `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile and `//= require jquery3` in your `app/assets/javascript/application.js` file.

Comment: you don't need to add jquery with a script tag, you already have it on your application.js, and also you are adding jquery twice with different versions with two script tags, just remove all and leave the application.js reference to jquery, then check the browser console and see if there's any error when running the site

Answer (score 0):

when you have jquery gem in your gem files 
you can include jquery library using

```
//= require jquery
```

in your application.js

which you already have done .

you need to remove these lines from your views

```
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and replace them with this line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: thanks for the help in that part of my code, really thanks, but i was referred to other error that i can t see, i don t know why (i update the question to give more information)